# sqoop.sqoop : Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem not found

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am facing issue while running `Sqoop` command to import tables from `Oracle DB` to `S3 file system`. I have configured all the required env variables and `hadoop-aws.jar` file is available in `lib` folder. Using `2.7` version of hadoop with Sqoop1.  This is single node cluster.

**Below is the issue:**

> Error: ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem not found java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem not found.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: ClassNotFound means that the libraries are not configured properly. Make sure the libraries path or CLASSPATH is set correctly.

Comment: Thanks Avinash for quick reply. I have configured all the libraries now in Sqoop lib and Hadoop lib directories. Below the error i am seeing now. Please help.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem could not be instantiated

Comment: This might be a version mismatch issue. Please check for the library version used.

Comment: Sqoop version 1.4.6 and Hadoop version is 2.7.0. Please check if these two are compatible.

Comment: I tried to see release notes, but no luck.